# CakePHP relations in Database

Tags: cakephp

I baked two controllers users and moves. Now I want to link the moves the users is linked to (only one). The bake did most of the work for me (thank god).

```
        <td><?= $user->has('move') ? $this->Html->link($user->move->name,       ['controller' => 'Moves', 'action' => 'view', $user->move->id]) : '' ?></td>
```

It actually show nothing. I have a foreign key in my database and the move 1 is correctly linked to the user.

foreign key in users "move_id" - primary key in the moves is "id"

I get no error and also no debug call. Any ideas?

Comment: Always include what version of CakePHP you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing nothing because in your ternary operator, it's executing this next portion >>>>>>>

```
    : ''
```

and therefore prints a blank. Your $user object probably doesn't have a field called "move".

You need to check the following:

1. Are associations defined for these two models?
2. In your controller, where you're fetching this $user before doing $this->set(.....), did you mention "contain"? Since you need to access the Users as well as the Moves models?

   For example:

   ```
    // If you're trying to find all users records

    $users = $this->Users->find('all')
           ->contain(['Moves']);        

    // For a single user record

    $users = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user("id"))
           ->contain(['Moves']);
   ```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD